# Explain how is heat map used in CNN for crowd count case?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, heatmap

im new to neural netwworks, and through the readings i often come across where heat maps are used in the network along with the ground truth provided with the dataset to (as far as my understanding is) evaluate the accuracy of network performance.

to be specific, consider the application of a crowd density estimation network, the dataset provide the crowd images, each image hase a corresponding ground truth .mat file, this file has: 
a matrix of X and Y coordinations representing the appearanse of human head in the image.
the total number of human heads in the image (crowd count) which is equal to the matrix rows.
my current understanding is that one image will get through the network and the result is a going to be compared with the given ground-truth (either the head locations, ore the crowd count),
SO, how and at which point and is the crowd density map or heat map is used? do we generate one for the image while training an compare it with the one generated from the ground truth? how is this done?

all the papers i've read neglect describing this process.
any clear explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The counting-by-density CNN approache, which you describe are fully convolutional regression network where the output is a density (heat map). That mean the training ground-truth data is a density map too. In general a MSE loss is used for training. The ground-truth density maps are in general precomputed from the head detection ground-truth.
E.g. if you look at the [MCNN code preparation folder](https://github.com/svishwa/crowdcount-mcnn/tree/master/data_preparation) you will find **get_density_map_gaussian.m** file which performs the density estimation from the ground-truth annotated head.